# I tried to install Cocoapods on my mac but got an 'No write permissions' error. Suggestions?

Tags: cocoapods

**Here is the command I entered:**

```
Mdn@Macbook ~ % gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6
```

**And here is the response I got:**

```
Fetching zeitwerk-2.6.11.gem
Fetching activesupport-6.1.7.6.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

**Please note:**

I am the owner and admin of this computer, so I am confused with the message that I don't have write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Below is the solution to my question. I found it on an Apple Developer Forum today.

1. Install homebrew via terminal (from this website: https://brew.sh)
2. After homebrew is successfully installed, add the following to the terminal: brew install cocoapods